# Calculate θ without iterative methods

Tags: math, trigonometry

Hi Could you please help me in the following issue.

I have three values R, S and T

and an equation,

R = S . sin θ + (T / cos θ).

How to find θ without using iterative methods?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths and would be better suited to maths-specific sites on the network.

Comment: `sin(theta) = sqrt(1 - cos(theta)^2)`, so this is a quadratic equation with one unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula exists but is [VERY long](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=R+cos%28x%29+%3D+T+%2B+S+sin%28x%29cos%28x%29).  (Solutions -> Exact forms -> case when R+T != 0)
You'd better stay with iterative algo.